# Mayavi "cannot open the connection" but plot works fine

Tags: python, mayavi, fedora-25

First, I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this but I default to StackOverflow for Python questions. And apologies if this is answered elsewhere but I did some Googling, grepping in the Python source, and searching here fruitlessly.

I've installed Mayavi 4.5.0 on a fairly fresh install of Fedora 25. I installed the SciPy stack from repositories by elevating to superuser with `su` and following [their instructions](https://www.scipy.org/install.html), following with `redhat-rpm-config` and `vtk-python`, since the Mayavi installation seemed to be demanding them. Then I installed Mayavi (and dependencies) with `pip install mayavi`. (Again, all as superuser, if relevant.)

Now, whenever I import mlab from Mayavi I get the error message

```
$ python -c "from mayavi import mlab"
Error in file(paste(tempdir(), "/Routput.txt", sep = ""), open = "wt+") : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(paste(tempdir(), "/Routput.txt", sep = ""), open = "wt+") :
  cannot open file '/tmp/Rtmpzdb1bt/Routput.txt': No such file or directory
```

In plotting scripts, everything still appears to work perfectly. Any ideas where this is coming from or how to fix it? It isn't presently a problem as far as I can tell, just irritating. Also, I don't get an error from `python -c "import mayavi"`.

Comment: Can you give the versioin of mayavi? `python -c "import mayavi; print mayavi.__version__"` There is no code in mayavi 4.5 containing `Routput`. I suspect an issue with the site settings of python. Does the error occur for any other program? Does it occur for `python -c "import mayavi"`?

Comment: Careful googling revealed this discussion http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2011-March.txt (search for "Routput.txt"). This appears to be an issue with the R capability of VTK. An hypothetical solution would be to install R with your package manager.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl `python -c "import mayavi"` gives no error and the Mayavi version is 4.5.0. I'll add this to the question. Also, R appears to be installed, version 3.3.2.

Comment: From the link above, I can only guess that vtk, when started, tests its "R" interface and fails. The current VTK repository does not show any code like the one above. What is the version of vtk?

Comment: VTK is version 6.3.0.

Comment: Hi, I cannot go further. Proper debugging would involve searching for the string "cannot open the connection" or "Routput.txt" in the mayavi, vtk, traits, traitsui, pyvtk packages on your computer. The `mlab.py` file does not reveal anything too specific unfortunately. Just as a random additional try, check that you have no `*.py` file in your current working directory that could ruin the import process.